# Send post from @PostBot using Telethon

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, telegram, telethon

Good afternoon, I want to know how to send this action from Telethon?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEhcX.png)

(Send post, click here to send post)

I tried to just send a message, but nothing comes out, only what I wrote is sent(@PostBot ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

```python
send_entity = await client.get_entity("USERNAME")
query = await client.inline_query("@PostBot", "62ed0f7189df3")
result = await query[0].click(send_entity)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).